# Adding embed within <div class="file-wrapper clearfix"> causes <div id="ds-options-wrapper"> to be nested within <div id="ds-body">

Tags: xml, xslt, nested, dspace

When I insert a JavaScript embed snippet to the end of the `<div class="file-wrapper clearfix"></div>` container within `item-view.xsl` of the Mirage theme, for some reason `<div id="ds-options-wrapper"></div>` found in `page-navigation.xsl` is generated outside of `<div id="ds-body"></div>`.

I wrote additional XSL within `<div class="file-wrapper clearfix"></div>` to include the JavaScript embed  only when an item has DOI available in `mets.xml`. Whenever DOI is available, the embed appears but will cause `<div id="ds-options-wrapper"></div>` to become a child of `<div id="ds-body"></div>`, instead of a sibling as it should be. Whenever there is no embed, `<div id="ds-options-wrapper"></div>` is a sibling of and directly follows `<div id="ds-body"></div>` as in the default Mirage template.

Why is this happening? I would like `<div id="ds-options-wrapper"></div>` to stay a sibling of `<div id="ds-body"></div>`

Here is a rough outline of what the generated DOM looks like with and without the embed:

**With Embed (psuedocode)**

```
<!-- id=" and class=" omitted -->
<div ds-content>
     <div ds-body>
          <div aspect_..._div_item-view>
               <div item-summary-view-metadata>
               </div>
               <div file-list>
                    <div file-wrapper clearfix>
                          thumbnail-wrapper
                          file metadata
                          <!-- EMBED APPEARS HERE -->
                          <div embed> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div item-summary-view-metadata>
                         URI
                         Date
                         etc...
                    </div>
                    <h2> appears in... </h2>
                    <ul> referenceSet-list </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ds-options-wrapper nested WITHIN ds-body for some reason -->
          <div ds-options-wrapper>
               .....
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Without Embed**

```
<!-- id=" and class=" omitted -->
<div ds-content>
     <div ds-body>
          <div aspect_..._div_item-view>
               <div item-summary-view-metadata>
               </div>
               <div file-list>
                    <div file-wrapper clearfix>
                          thumbnail-wrapper
                          file metadata
                          <!-- NO EMBED HERE -->
                    </div>
               </div> <!-- file-list ends here ?? -->
               <div item-summary-view-metadata>
                         URI
                         Date
                         etc...
               </div>
               <h2> appears in... </h2>
               <ul referenceSet-list> </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
     <!-- ds-options-wrapper nested OUTSIDE ds-body like normal -->
     <div ds-options-wrapper>
          .....
     </div>
</div>
```

Although it doesn't seem like it should matter,

**here is the code I've inserted into `item-view.xsl`**

```
<xsl:template match="mets:file">
        <xsl:param name="context" select="."/>
        <div class="file-wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
                ....
            </div>
            <div class="file-metadata">
                ....
            </div>
            <!-- INSERTED CODE TO GENERATE JS EMBED HERE -->
            <!-- Only output is either .... -->
            <xsl:variable name="quoteChar">"</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//dim:field[@element='identifier'][@qualifier='doi']">
                    <xsl:variable name="doiVar" select="//dim:field[@element='identifier'][@qualifier='doi']"></xsl:variable>
                    <!-- HERE -->
                    <div data-badge-type='medium-donut' class='altmetric-embed' data-badge-details='right' data-doi='{$doiVar}'></div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(//dim:field[@element='identifier'][@qualifier='citation'],'doi')">
                        <xsl:variable name="parseThis" select="//dim:field[@element='identifier'][@qualifier='citation']"></xsl:variable>

                        <xsl:variable name="tokenized" select="str:split($parseThis, 'doi:')" />
                        <xsl:for-each select="$tokenized">
                            <xsl:variable name="curtoken" select="."/>
                            <xsl:if test="contains($curtoken, '10.') and contains($curtoken, '/')">
                                <xsl:variable name="newtext">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="string-trim">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$curtoken" />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <!-- OR HERE -->
                                <div data-badge-type='medium-donut' class='altmetric-embed' data-badge-details='right' data-doi='{$newtext}'></div>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!-- End Code -->

         </div> <!-- end .file-wrapper clearfix-->
</xsl:template>
```

Note that when an embed exists then for some reason `<div class="file-list>` will also encapsulate nodes containing URI and Date, etc., but it does not do so when no embed exists.

What does the `context` parameter do? I see it called from within the template generating `<div class="file-list">`. In fact I don't have a clear idea at all what goes on inside the this template:

```
<div class="file-list">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="...">
                      ... 
                      <!-- what goes on here? -->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mets:file">
                        <!-- what goes on here? -->
                        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$context"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the empty div elements. It's a known issue that empty XHTML elements break the XHTML structure in older DSpace themes. You can fix this by adding a non-breaking space in the div:

```
<div data-badge-type='medium-donut' class='altmetric-embed' data-badge-details='right' data-doi='{$doiVar}'>&#160;</div>
```

If you search for &#160 in the Mirage code you will see there are quite a lot of occurrences.

This issue is solved in Mirage 2.

Comment: Many thanks. Finally got around to testing this and it is indeed the solution.